# Automated testing of webrtc application?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, mocha.js, webrtc

I am developing a conferencing app, details:

- target: chrome browser
- server: node.js ( currently windows env)

simplest test scenario would be:

1. open two browser tabs( open browser if need be)
2. emulate button click on both.
3. emulate accept getUserMedia request( **hardest part**)
4. more emulation stuff and reading JavaScript variable values and verifying them.

Till now, I have been doing manual testing for all of this, but decided that it would be impractical for the long run.
I have not done much automated testing( just a bit of unit testing). Initially, i thought `mocha` would do the job, but beginning to think it is not enough.

I need some pointers as to what are `tools or alternate test frameworks` needed to achieve browser starting, tab opening and giving media sharing permissions.

Comment: Load multiplier supports webrtc testing. You may like to follow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35464046/1861447).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome has command line flags for skipping get getUserMedia permission as well as using fake devices:

- --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream (skips GUM permission prompt)
- --use-fake-device-for-media-stream (uses a fake device)

Check http://blog.andyet.com/2014/09/29/testing-webrtc-applications, http://googletesting.blogspot.se/2014/08/chrome-firefox-webrtc-interop-test-pt-1.html for background information

If you want to click buttons, the standard tool for this is selenium. If you prefer Javascript to Java, a binding such as webdriver.io might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you like Ruby, take a look at Capybara.  You'll probably also want to use Xvfb so that you can run the tests on a machine that doesn't have a display.

Here is an example snippet that will let you open Chome with the switches that Philipp suggests.  I've used this to create a headless video recording test.

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  switches = %w(disable-popup-blocking disable-translate use-fake-ui-for-media-stream use-fake-device-for-media-stream test-type)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, switches: switches)
end
```

Comment: for some reason as of the current version of Capybara, I can't seem to get the syntax (NOT seen here) that uses  `'chromeOptions' => {      'args' => [ ... ] }` to work correctly… the syntax above works for me and I see the green test video

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for webrtc testing, you may like to see loadmultiplier.., it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35464046/1861447) previously.